# Two column Null Should comes first

Tags: sql, sql-server

Test table has two columns A and B. I want to get null values for both columns ie. should show first from test table.Script for creating test table:

```
create table test(a varchar(25),b varchar(30))

insert into test
select 'a',null
insert into test
select 'b',null
insert into test
select null,d
insert into test
select null,e
insert into test
select 'f',null
insert into test
select 'a',null
insert into test
select null,b

After insert output looks like
a   NULL
b   NULL
NULL d
NULL e
f   NULL
a   NULL
NULL b
```

Sql Query should return null values first for column a and b.

Output should comes below.

```
output
-----------
a      b
-----------
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL
a    NULL
a    b
b    d
f    e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH TableA AS
(
SELECT a, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a) AS RowNumber FROM test
)
, TableB AS
(
SELECT b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b) AS RowNumber FROM test
)
SELECT a,b
FROM TableA AS TA INNER JOIN TableB AS TB
ON TA.RowNumber = TB.RowNumber
```

Should do the job. I have tested it and it works with your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM @TABLE
ORDER BY CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE a END ASC,
         CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE b END ASC
```

### [`WORKING SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1905/1)

Comment: This doesn't return the results required.

Comment: @AshShah Have a look at the sql fiddle I have just created.

Comment: You can make this shorter by using `ORDER BY ISNULL(a, '1'), ISNULL(b, '1')`.

Comment: @M.Ali your test data is not the same as the test data provided in the question.